# Changing function in R namespace

Tags: r

I'm pulling my hair out over this seemingly simple problem. I am trying to change a function in the hglm package; specifically the private hglm.default function.

Here is what I've done:

`library(hglm)
e<-loadNamespace("hglm")
unlockBinding("hglm.default",e)
assignInNamespace("hglm.default",...my edits...,ns="hglm",envir=e)
lockBinding("hglm.default",e)`

However, when I do

`environment(hglm:::hglm.default)`

I get

`<environment: R_GlobalEnv>`

which is problematic; it needs to be in the namespace environment for hglm (`<environment: namespace:hglm>`) or else it doesn't work. If I try to set the environment with

`environment(hglm:::hglm.default)<-e`

I get the error

`Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘*tmp*’`

I've tried all sorts of permutations of this and can't seem strike the right one. I am a total novice on namespaces, etc, so hopefully someone knowledgable can help out!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not look like a statistical question. It might be off topic here. Perhaps Stack Overflow would be the right place to ask?

Comment: I toyed with the idea - I figured out a fix anyway (once I posted this of course...). If you set the environment of the edited function prior to using `assignInNamespace`, then the copy that gets placed in the namespace has the correct environment. I'm not sure why you can't do this post-hoc, but that seems to be the case.

Comment: What is the objective? Why are you changing f-n in the namespace?

Comment: I would not have guessed that `loadNamespace` would return an R environment. Why wouldn't the value passed to the 'e' argument be `environment(hglm)`?

Comment: Both `loadNamespace("hglm")` and `environment(hglm)` return the correct environment, but I think (don't quote me on this) it's safer to use the `loadNamespace` version. So yes, you could have passed 'e' the environment with the other command.

Comment: @Aksakal - I wanted the hglm function to return the variance-covariance matrix for the fixed effect coefficients in the statistical model. The function was doing this already but not returning the value with object. I modified the function so that the matrix was part of the return object. It had to be replaced in the environment so that it could use the private functions in the namespace.